# Is there a closed form for $\sup_{f,0\le x\le 1}(1-x)f(x)/\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, optimization

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of continuous and strictly increasing functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$. Is there a closed form for $$\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F},0\le x\le 1}\frac{(1-x)f(x)}{\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}?$$

That is, the ratio of the following dark area to the integral area.

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it's $1$, right? Approximate the constant function $1$ by strictly increasing functions.

Comment: @TheoBendit Sorry that I missed the condition that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Doesn't matter; just approximate it pointwise. Pick a point $(\varepsilon, 1 - \varepsilon)$ for tiny $\varepsilon > 0$, and draw straight lines from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$. Then pick $x = \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x^{a}$, for $a\in (0,1)$. Then
$$\sup_{x\in [0,1]}\frac{(1-x)f(x)}{\int_0^1f(t)\,dt}=(a+1)\sup_{x\in [0,1]}(1-x)x^a=\left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)^a.$$
which goes to $1$ as $a\to 0^+$.

Moreover, for all $x\in [0,1]$, and for any strictly increasing functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, we have that
$$\int_0^1f(t)\,dt\geq \int_{x}^1f(t)dt\geq f(x)\int_x^1dt=f(x)(1-x).$$
So the desired $\sup$ is $1$. Note that the condition $f(0)=0$ is irrelevant.