# Is there a closed form for $\inf_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\sup_{0\le x\le 1}(1-x)f(x)/\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, optimization

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of continuous and strictly increasing functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$. Is there a closed form for $$\inf_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\sup_{0\le x\le 1}\frac{(1-x)f(x)}{\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}?$$

That is, the ratio of the following dark area to the integral area.

[image]

---

Note: this question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185021/280596), but this time I want to minimize the ratio when $f$ varies.

Comment: How did you obtain $\frac{1}{4(1-\varepsilon)}$?

Comment: @Uskebasi By symmetry we can assume $x\le 1-\epsilon$, then $f(x)=\frac{x\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$, so we have $\frac{(1-x)f(x)}{\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{(1-x)x\epsilon}{(1-\epsilon)\epsilon}$, which has a maximum of $\frac{1}{4(1-\epsilon)}$.

Comment: @xskxzr Where does this nice problem come from?

Comment: @RobertZ It comes from a research, and I formalize it as this mathematical problem by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desired infimum is zero.
For $\epsilon\in (0,1/2)$, consider the strictly increasing continuous function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\epsilon x}{1-x}& \text{if $x\in [0,1-\epsilon]$},\\
x& \text{if $x\in [1-\epsilon,1]$.}
\end{cases}$$
Then
$$\int_0^1f(t)\,dt =\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}-\epsilon\log(\epsilon)$$
and $\sup_{x\in [0,1]}(1-x)f(x)=\epsilon(1-\epsilon)$.
Hence, as $\epsilon \to 0^+$
$$\frac{\sup_{x\in [0,1]}(1-x)f(x)}{\int_0^1f(t)\,dt }=\frac{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}{\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}-\epsilon\log(\epsilon)}=\frac{1-\epsilon}{\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\log(1/\epsilon)}\to 0^+.$$