Find the $\inf_{f\in M}\sup_{x\in[0,1]}$ of the given expression
Let $M$ be a set of continuous decreasing functions $f$ on the segment  $[0,1]$ for which $f(1)=0$. Find the
$$\inf_{f\in M}\left(\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\frac{xf(x)}{\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm dt}\right)$$
I will be grateful for any help!

Welcome to MathSE! What have you tried?

I've tried to suppose what answer is 0. Because our expression is positive. And tried to find a family of functions, which make our expression near to 0. For example, f(x)= (1-x) ^n where n goes to infinity, and some other functions. But I couldn't find a good functions. After that I tried to construct different inequalities with integrals, it also didn't work

I don't think the question is answerable with the given information... Since the denominator of the fraction is constant for a given $f$, one would need to maximize $xf(x)$, which isn't possible with the given information

@Aro: Add all of that and why it didn't work etc. in the question otherwise it will attract downvotes.

I've found the solution for similar question. To solve my task, we can replace in this solution x to 1-x, and the answer will be 0. I also tried to find a good functions, to prove desired answer - 0 https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188694/1362378

@Aro: From the link you cited, it's the same problem, not just similar. Just set $g(x) = f(1-x)$ then use the answer there
